# Black Stains on sword model

Tags: modeling

Hi so my problem is that on the hande as you can see are visible black stains, ive checked normals and cleanup>merge by distance and yet nothing[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using a Normal Map node?

Comment: Ive added my nodes to the post

Comment: I suggest a strength between .1 and .3 for the Normal Map node, should make things more "normal" :p

Comment: Also anything but the base color should be set to non-color data

Comment: It works now!!! thanks sm for fast help <3